# Error with Web Service in Liferay 7

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, liferay

I am working with Liferay 7 in Eclipse Mars and I am trying to implement a SOAP web service with Axis but I'm getting the following error during the deployment:

"Publishing to Liferay 7.x at localhost... has encountred a problem Unable to build output
Unable to build output
Could not execute build using Gradle distribution
https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-bin.zip"

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfK87.png)

If I remove the web service everything works correctly.

Thanks.

Comment: How are you creating the web service project?

Comment: What I did with the Assistant of Eclipse.

I think that I have solved the problem, but now when the Send call my WebService method, sends null parameters. For more reference I'm rewriting the liferay authentication hook.

Comment: OK we can look at it from another side. What are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to do a custom integration?